# Creating button that axios.post something from input

Tags: javascript, function, button, input, axios

I have to create a button that will do an axios.post request, if something is in the input.
Im stuck, my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <title>zad2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="newInput" data-test="todo-input" placeholder="wpisz tekst"><button id="newButton" data-test="todo-add" onClick="addToDoElem()">Dodaj</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my js:

```
const $newTask;
let $newInput = document.getElementById('.newInput');

let $newButton;
function addToDoElem() {
  if ($newInput.value !== '') {
    axios.post(
      $newTask = $newInput.value;
    )
  }
}
```

Appreciate any tips. Have a nice day!

Comment: `document.querySelector('.newInput')` won’t select anything here. You element does not have a _class_ `newInput`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `document.getElementById('.newInput');` by `document.getElementById('#newInput');`, `getElementById()` gets DOM element by his id, not his class.